# proper syntax for onclick in an echo?

Tags: javascript, php

I have an echo statement that doesn't call an onclick function. The onclick function works properly called if it's not in the if statement (it works too if included in a larger echo chunk) .

```
if ($varGetProductArray1[4] > 0){
                    echo '  <div id ="sizeButton1" class="sizeButton" onclick="ryanClicked(\'sizeButton1\',\'sizeButton2\',\'sizeButton3\')">      S </div> ' ;
            }
```

I'm sure that $varGetProductArray1[4] is correct (it wouldn't display the html if it wasn't). I have tried changing out the " and ' for the parameters but to no avail.

My js is being called outside php

```
 <script type='text/javascript' src="mylib.js"></script>
```

but i tried `echo '<script type='text/javascript' src="ryan.js"></script>'` as well and that didn't work.

```
<div id="sizeButton1" class="sizeButton" onclick="ryanClicked(&quot;sizeButton1&quot;,&quot;sizeButton2&quot;,&quot;sizeButton3&quot;)">      S </div>  is the &quot not working??
```

Comment: Can you add the html output? (View source in browser)

Comment: The code is working 1:1 on my side when the "button" is showing (whitout if statement). And you say the button html is showing on you. I made a pseudo function to check the function calling. I think the problem is in your JS function that does not do what it should. Make `console.log(var);` in your JS function right after the function starts for your parameters and check your console. What do you recieve? When you recieve the correct param inputs then its nothing wrong with this case.

Comment: i think perhaps the &quot; isn't working as a ' should?

Comment: what function did you successfully call? was it within the onclick? my js function works when outside the if statement so I don't think the js function is incorrect.

Comment: nevermind you were right! ahaha thank you. There was a trailing comma in my param list. I'll upvote when I get to 15 rep